# css property working on button click but not inside $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code.

Following code works fine on click but not inside $.each. Why?

```
$($('.slides').children()[0]).css({'opacity':1,'z-index':6});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on('click', '.one', function() {
$('.slides').children().css({'opacity':0,'z-index':0});
                $($('.slides').children()[0]).css({'opacity':1,'z-index':6});
});

$(document).on('click', '.two', function() {
$('.slides').children().css({'opacity':0,'z-index':0});
                $($('.slides').children()[1]).css({'opacity':1,'z-index':6});
});

$(document).on('click', '.three', function() {
$('.slides').children().css({'opacity':0,'z-index':0});
                $($('.slides').children()[2]).css({'opacity':1,'z-index':6});
});

$(document).on('click', '.left-btn', function() {
        var i = 0;

        $.each($('.slides > li'),function(e,v){
            if($(v).css('opacity')>0){
                $('.slides').children().css({'opacity':0,'z-index':0});
                $($('.slides').children()[i]).css({'opacity':1,'z-index':6});
                
                console.log("SSSSSSSSSSS"+i);
            }
            i++;
        });
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn left-btn">
left
</button>

<button class="btn one">
one
</button>
<button class="btn two">
two
</button>
<button class="btn three">
three
</button>
<ul class="slides">
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what you want to do when you click on `Left` button?

Comment: if third li visible then show second, if second then show first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change left button code to the following. When you click on `left` button, previous `li` element is displayed. I have written `if` statement to check whether the current `li` is first element, if yes then I don't do any thing.

```
$(document).on('click', '.left-btn', function () {
    $.each($('.slides > li'), function (e, v) {
        if ($(v).css('opacity') > 0) {
            if ($(v).index() != 0) {
                $('.slides').children().css({ 'opacity': 0, 'z-index': 0 });
                //$(v).prev().css({ 'opacity': 1, 'z-index': 6 });
                $($('.slides').children()[e-1]).css({'opacity':1,'z-index':6});
            }
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.right-btn', function () {
    var flag = false;
    $.each($('.slides > li'), function (e, v) {
        if ($(v).css('opacity') > 0) {
            if ($(v).index() != $('.slides > li').length - 1 && !flag) {
                $('.slides').children().css({ 'opacity': 0, 'z-index': 0 });
                $($('.slides').children()[e + 1]).css({ 'opacity': 1, 'z-index': 6 });
                //$(v).next().css({ 'opacity': 1, 'z-index': 6 });
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.one', function () {
 $('.slides').children().css({ 'opacity': 0, 'z-index': 0 });
 $($('.slides').children()[0]).css({ 'opacity': 1, 'z-index': 6 });
});

$(document).on('click', '.two', function () {
 $('.slides').children().css({ 'opacity': 0, 'z-index': 0 });
 $($('.slides').children()[1]).css({ 'opacity': 1, 'z-index': 6 });
});

$(document).on('click', '.three', function () {
 $('.slides').children().css({ 'opacity': 0, 'z-index': 0 });
 $($('.slides').children()[2]).css({ 'opacity': 1, 'z-index': 6 });
});

$(document).on('click', '.left-btn', function () {
 $.each($('.slides > li'), function (e, v) {
  if ($(v).css('opacity') > 0) {
   if ($(v).index() != 0) {
    $('.slides').children().css({ 'opacity': 0, 'z-index': 0 });
    //$(v).prev().css({ 'opacity': 1, 'z-index': 6 });
        $($('.slides').children()[e-1]).css({'opacity':1,'z-index':6});
   }
  }
 });
});

$(document).on('click', '.right-btn', function () {
 var flag = false;
 $.each($('.slides > li'), function (e, v) {
  if ($(v).css('opacity') > 0) {
   if ($(v).index() != $('.slides > li').length - 1 && !flag) {
    $('.slides').children().css({ 'opacity': 0, 'z-index': 0 });
    $($('.slides').children()[e + 1]).css({ 'opacity': 1, 'z-index': 6 });
    //$(v).next().css({ 'opacity': 1, 'z-index': 6 });
    flag = true;
   }
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn left-btn">
 left
</button>
<button class="btn one">
 one
</button>
<button class="btn two">
 two
</button>
<button class="btn three">
 three
</button>
<button class="btn right-btn">
    right
</button>
<ul class="slides">
 <li>first</li>
 <li>second</li>
 <li>third</li>
 <li>fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But why my code is not working? as same .css() function working fine outside $.each

Comment: I have updated my snippet to your code, it works, instead of using a separate variable `i`, use can use `e` which maintains index. Then `e-1` gets handle to previous element. You can verify my updated code. You can shorten your code using `prev` method of jQuery.

Comment: You need to move to the next element. Updated code above.